# How do I consume a CouchDB view on an Android offline?

Tags: android, couchdb, cloudant, couchbase-lite

For example we have created this view:
http://cdb.linkaform.com/client_126_catalog_records/_design/paises/_view/paises-key

How can we consume this View on an Android?  We are using the CouchBase and Cloudant library.

Comment: What do you mean by "consume"?  If you mean use it offline, you cannot do that with CouchDB views.  You need to create a view using Couchbase Lite (which is unaffiliated with CouchDB, mostly) if you want to use it offline.

Comment: SyncAndroid (and its iOS cousin CDTDatastore) don’t support views. The query paradigm is Mango/Cloudant Query for the on-device libraries from Cloudant.

Comment: Thanks @borrden. Yes by "consume" I mean use it offline.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for using remote views at least in Cloudant Sync.

The approach in both libraries is to replicate the documents into the local storage using the native replication mechanism. Once the information is replicated you should use the data selection mechanism provided by each library.

- Cloudant Sync provides a Mango-like query syntax that allows to retrieve the documents you require. [https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/query.md]
- Couchbase Mobile 2.0, includes a similar query mechanism [https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/2.0/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/query/index.html], previous versions support the definition of local views with this purpose.